# Why does this Rails code work if there are methods declared outside the Contoller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Why does this code work if the `private` statement is written outside the class and the methods `login_params` and `permitted_params` are also declared outside the class?

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   respond_to :json
   skip_before_filter :user_is_signed_in, only: :create

   def create
     ...
   end

end

private

def login_params
   permitted_params.extract!(:email, :password).permit!
end

def permitted_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username,     :first_name, :last_name)
end
```

Comment: Are you calling these methods in the controller?

Comment: @Santosh , Yes, inside the create method

Comment: if you add to `login_params` method `puts self` and calling `login_params` inside `create` action you should see `#<RegistrationsController:0x007f97d44391d0>` in log, so i think Rails create controller class in runtime with all content inside file `registrations_controller.rb`

Comment: @Зелёный maybe you know more details about that process?

Comment: @IS04 I just think so, I'm not sure that's true, i am sure that is nothing about `Object`. Dig into Rails source to find answer =).

Comment: also we have `self.class #=> Object` before `class UserController ...; end;` and `self.class #=> UserController` after controller definition, so it's looks like after controller definition we have something like `cd UserController` in `pry`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Ruby scripts are executed in global scope (AFAIK it's Object class),so methods `login_params` and `permitted_params` declared in this scope. There are no criminal to call any method in global scope.

For example, run next script:

```
class Test
  def test_method
    puts private_global_called
  end
end

private

def private_global_called
  'Private called!'
end

Test.new.test_method # Private called!
puts Object.send(:private_global_called) # Private called!
```

Answer (score 3):

"When a method is declared private in Ruby, it means this method can never be called with an explicit receiver. "

As no explicit receiver is required to call those methods within the controller class itself, then it still works.

http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/